# Filemaker Pro execute SQL select - where are results?

Tags: sql, select, odbc, filemaker

I am trying to run a select query using Filemaker Pro.  Apparently this is possible in V12 and V13 via the "Execute SQL" script step.

What I have done is created a FM script called "Find containers" which uses the "Execute SQL" script step to run a select query on an ODBC data connection (to MS SQL tables).  Then I created a button in filemaker that triggers that script to run.

In sql, if I run a query, my "select" results appear in the form of a table on screen immediately.  However, when I click the button in Filemaker Pro that runs my script/select query, nothing happens on screen.  Where should I be seeing the results of my select statement?  Am I missing the point of what FM Pro is supposed to be offering with Execute SQL?

Answer (score 3):

The Execute SQL Script doesn't have a way to return the results of a Select. It's more for executing other kinds of SQL Statements.

What you want is the Import Records Script step.  You will find one of the options to be import from ODBC source.  See the image.

[image]

Comment: Can you give a real-life example of what types of things executeSQL is intended for?  My FM pro database is already connected live to SQL via ODBC, so I'm not trying to import records.  The data is already in the DB I was just hoping I could avoid the tedious process of "finding" results via FM pro and use a simple single script instead of enter find mode, set field, copy/paste etc.  Hmm

Comment: It sounds like you are using ESS ( External SQL Sources ) - http://www.filemaker.com/support/technologies/sql.html.  If thats so, then neither the script step will help you.  You are going to have to do finds the FileMaker way.

Comment: ESS wraps normal FileMaker behavior around a SQL backend like MySQL. So you interact with the Data using FileMaker finds, etc.

The Script Step ExecuteSQL is intended to Execute SQL on ODBC data sources, But you don't get any "result set" back.  People use it for adding records to DB or calling stored procedures.